# Is it possible to hide a domain record from an "any" query in bind9?

Tags: domain-name-system, bind

Lets say I have example.com. On this domain there are public services, like www, mail, etc. Those will have records like:

```
www in A 1.2.3.4
mail in A 1.2.3.4
```

Then I also have a VPN in another location, so I want to add this record:

```
vpn in A 5.6.7.8
```

But if someone wants to query my domain, they can run:

```
dig example.com any
```

Which will return

```
www in A 1.2.3.4
mail in A 1.2.3.4
vpn in A 5.6.7.8
```

But I want `vpn` to be excluded from that list. The IP would only be visible to someone who knows that the subdomain exists in the first place. (Yeah, I know this isn't strong security)

Comment: That's not how `ANY` queries work.

Comment: That's the result i'm getting. Are they cached in nameserver that my local system uses?

Comment: When I type `dig example.com any` I do not see any subdomains. Only if I am able to guess that there is a subdomain called `www` I can see the records in that subdomain by typing `dig www.example.com any`.

Comment: Strange, i just tried again on example.com and I only get the NS servers. earlier I was getting much more: dig example.com any .... example.com.  80910 IN A 93.184.216.34
example.com.  81397 IN AAAA 2606:2800:220:1:248:1893:25c8:1946
example.com.  63962 IN NS a.iana-servers.net.
example.com.  63962 IN NS b.iana-servers.net.
example.com.  3598 IN SOA sns.dns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2016110720 7200 3600 1209600 3600

Comment: A 'zone transfer' would give them the full set, but ANY does not.

Comment: DAB, I agree with the above. It is impossible to get that result from that query. You made a mistake somewhere.